# Joomla! Shopping Cart Extension Recommendation for Photography

Tags: joomla-3.x

Im a landscape and nature photog.  Im looking for a good, opensource, easy to use shopping cart to sell my photography.  I really want to spend most of my time taking pics not maintaining my shopping cart.  Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 2):

[Event Gallery](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/event-gallery) is an attractive and robust Gallery which includes e-commerce features such as a shopping cart module.

The extension is developed by photographer Sven Blüge.

There are various layout options including a "mosaic" layout which does a great job of displaying portrait and landscape photos, that don't necessarily have consistent dimensions, together on the same page.

There is a free and a paid version. The paid version includes a content plugin so that you can insert galleries into articles.

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from VirtueMart. It's not at all what it used to be (it was the reason why many website owners used to Joomla), and most of our clients using it are migrating in droves to non-hosted system such as Shopify, 3DCart, and BigCommerce. Shopify is probably the easiest of these 3.

If your shop is really simple, and you don't want to pay a monthly fee (+ transaction fees) for your shop, then you can go with RokQuickCart. It works and it's very simple to use (hence the word Quick in its name).

Going back to VirtueMart, the problems started with the migration from VirtueMart 1 to VirtueMart 2, which was even messier than the migration from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5. I have no idea why the VirtueMart people didn't create a reliable tool to do that. Even if you use VirtueMart 2 from scratch, you are faced with a myriad of problems, ranging from simple things, such as creating variations of your products (which is super messy in VM 2) to complex things, such as handling the security of your store. The checkout process is also extremely confusing in VM and deters conversions (you will know what I mean if you use it).

All in all, it is worth it to invest in a non-self-hosted shop if you can afford it and you are willing to pay their fees (expect to pay something like 3% of your total transaction so that they can process it for you, also expect to pay a monthly fee that it is around $30/month). You don't have to worry about the security of your shop, you don't have to worry about the technical aspects of your shop, and adding/updating products in your store is relatively much easier than using VM.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Good to know.  Right now I cant afford to pay at all. So I'll go take a look at rok. Thanks bunches. Tim

Comment: Have you considered Etsy?  I don't think they have a monthly fee, and it's generally easier to get seen on a site like that than going alone.  It has a ready-made audience of people who buy art.  Although they take a percentage, it may be more cost-effective, and certainly less time consuming.  

There's also RedBubble who would be seen as more commercial, but who would handle printing for you (albeit at a larger cost). 

I think the monthly fee is rare on sites like these.

Comment: If your work is very commercial, then stock photo sites might be worth looking at too.